# Rendering problems with Three.js

Tags: three.js

I have a code here: http://tinyurl.com/qbsue7m

I don't know why, but my forex candles don't display correctly.
Why is that little white column appears in the green candle?

Comment: The white columns are your shadowmesh ... I see them in all the candles by the way.

Comment: Thank you, it works now, I was using negative numbers, that was the problem.